# find closest date from array obj/property js

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, properties

I'm trying to get the closest date from now from an array and use it in the countdown timer along with that objects associated properties like event.

I've managed to get this far, from looking around on the web, but my code only pulls the last entry from the array not the closest date.

If anyone can help or push me in the right direction that would be great.

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="celebration"></p>

<script>
  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var data = [
    {
      date: "04/10/2021",
      event: "event 1",
    },
    {
      date: "08/15/2022",
      event: "event 2",
    },
    {
      date: "09/15/2021",
      event: "event 3",
    },
    {
      date: "01/12/2025",
      event: "event 4",
    },
  ];

  var closest = data.reduce((a, b) => (a.date - now < b.date - now ? a : b));

  console.log(closest.date);

  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date(closest.date);

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(
      (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    document.getElementById("celebration").innerHTML = closest.event;
    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      document.getElementById("celebration").innerHTML = "None";
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: The objects in your array with the property `date` are strings. To treaat them as dates you'll need to first parse them

Comment: what if there is `expired` date. Do you still want that or the next one which is not expired?

Comment: hi @decpk yeah if a date in the array has past (expired) i wouldn't want to show it and move onto the next one

Comment: Then just sort it and get the first data that is not expired simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is make sure you have a method to convert your US-format date into a javascript `Date` instance:

```js
const usFormattedDate = "08/15/2022"

const parseUSDate = str => {
  const parts = str.split("/");
  return new Date(Date.UTC(
    parseInt(parts[2],10),
    parseInt(parts[0],10)-1,
    parseInt(parts[1],10)));
}

console.log(parseUSDate(usFormattedDate))
```

Why not simply use the `Date` constructor or `Date.parse` method? As the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters) say:

> Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

Then you can use this code to parse your `date` properties - but you probably only want to do this once per object rather than twice per comparison

```js
const parseUSDate = str => {
  const parts = str.split("/");
  return new Date(Date.UTC(
    parseInt(parts[2], 10),
    parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1,
    parseInt(parts[1], 10)));
}

var now = new Date().getTime();

var data = [{
    date: "04/10/2021",
    event: "event 1",
  },
  {
    date: "08/15/2022",
    event: "event 2",
  },
  {
    date: "09/15/2021",
    event: "event 3",
  },
  {
    date: "01/12/2025",
    event: "event 4",
  },
];

var closest = data
  .map(x => ({ ...x, date: parseUSDate(x.date) })) // Convert date to an actual date
  .filter(x => x.date > now)                       // remove records in the past
  .reduce((a, b) => (a.date - now < b.date - now ? a : b));

console.log(closest);
```

Note that having done it this way (converting the `date` property) there is no need for this line:

```
var countDownDate = new Date(closest.date);
```

It's just simply

```
var countDownDate = closest.date;
```

Comment: thanks so much for doing that and explaining it. i did not take into account that it would show dates that are in the past as closest. how would you edit that so that it doesn't show a date if it has expired (in the past) and then move onto the next closest date

Comment: @mike in between the `map` and `reduce` use a `filter(x => x.date > now)` - see updated answer

Answer (score -1):

You can just `sort` it and find the first element that is not expired

```
  const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
  const closest = sorted.find(o => new Date(o.date) - now > 0)
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="celebration"></p>

<script>
  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var data = [{
      date: "04/10/2021",
      event: "event 1",
    },
    {
      date: "08/15/2022",
      event: "event 2",
    },
    {
      date: "09/15/2021",
      event: "event 3",
    },
    {
      date: "01/12/2025",
      event: "event 4",
    },
  ];

  // var closest = data.reduce( ( a, b ) => ( new Date(a.date) - now < new Date(b.date) - now ? a : b ) );
  const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
  const closest = sorted.find(o => new Date(o.date) - now > 0)

  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date(closest.date);

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(
      (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    document.getElementById("celebration").innerHTML = closest.event;
    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      document.getElementById("celebration").innerHTML = "None";
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: @mike `Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.` - see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters)

Comment: @Jamiec what to use instead of `Date` constructor

Comment: @decpk see my answer. Or something like date-fns